# convergence test

Tags: calculus

show that a function of cos(n) diverges and prove.

Comment: If you want to show that it diverges, you need to prove that you **cannot** find such an $N$ for all $s$. Actually this question is easier if you write down the first several term and see what it is.

Comment: Assume you have such an $N$, then write the inequality for $N+1$...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** You have, **for all** $p \geq0$:
$$
\cos (2p\:\pi )=1,
$$ and
$$
\cos ( (2p+1)\pi)=-1.
$$

Comment: @Lydia It is OK! (you meant |-1-s|<1)